# How do I assign a default value to Map type variable in a class constructor?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a class constructor where the only parameter is of Map type.

```
class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map initialProduct;

  ProductManager(this.initialProduct =  {'title': '', 'image': ''});

}
```

I'm getting these two errors:

> Named parameters must be enclosed in curly braces ('{' and '}').dart(named_parameter_outside_group)

---

> Default values of an optional parameter must be
>   constant.dart(non_constant_default_value)

Changing my code in the following way, I solved the second error:

```
ProductManager(this.initialProduct =  const {'title': '', 'image': ''});
```

What am I doing wrong? Why Map variables are different from other types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only give a default value to an optional, named parameter. The named parameters are included in the constructor declaration in curly brackets. Try this:

```
class ProductManager {
  final Map initialProduct;

  ProductManager({this.initialProduct = const {'title': '', 'image': ''}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) 

Researching a little further, I learned that parameters between curly braces are optional named parameters, and parameters between square brackets, are optional positional parameters.

Comment: How can you do to add a new element to the map after a ProductManager has been created ?
If you do, myProductManager.initialProduct[newKey]=newValue, you will throw this error : Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable Map.
The created map cannot be modified. Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 5):

If you give a default value to the optional, named parameter like below, you will not be abble to modify your default constant map

```
class MyClass {
  Map myMap;

  MyClass({this.myMap = const {}});
}

main() {
 MyClass a = MyClass();
 a.myMap[0]=1; // Throw error
}
```

The code will throw this error because you cannot modify a constant:

> Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable Map

To resolve this issue, you can init the `myMap` value when the instance of `MyClass` is created.

```
class MyClass {
  Map myMap;

  MyClass({this.myMap = const {}});
}

main() {
 MyClass a = MyClass({}); // Provide a non const map
 a.myMap[0]=1; // Will work
}
```

Or you can also don't fill a default value in the constructor, an change the value of the map by calling the attribute or a function directly

```
class MyClass {
  Map myMap = {}; // Provide an empty map 

  MyClass(); // Don't provide a default constructor
}

main() {
 MyClass a = MyClass();
 a.myMap[0]=1; // Will work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2024 update on this issue, since I had the same.

To summarise, the task at hand is to create a class around a Map with an ability to pass a Map as a constructor parameter optionally. We want to have the field holding the Map `final` while keeping the Map itself mutable.

This seems useful when the Map provides an initial state only, while we want to encapsulate managing the further modifications of the Map.

As Adrien Arcuri mentioned in their answer, the problem is that if you do this intuitively, it doesn't work:

```
// ❌ WON'T COMPILE
class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map product;

  ProductManager({
    this.product = {/* some initial state */},
  });
}
```

The compiler wants you to do this instead passing a compile-time constant empty Map as a default value for your final class property (`this.product = const {}`):

```
// ❌ WILL FAIL AT RUNTIME IF WE MODIFY `this.product`
class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map product;

  ProductManager({
    this.product = const {/* initial state */},
  });
}
```

If you do this, the problem will occur at runtime when you attempt to change that map by adding data into it.

However, you can still achieve what you aim if you choose a different syntax for the constructor and leverage its [initializer list](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializer-list).
Also we should **always clone** the passed in initial collection value, otherwise we break the class' encapsulation.

So 3 changes in the example below:

1. Declare `product` as a regular named function parameter and not an [initializing formal parameter](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializing-formal-parameters)
2. Use [initializer list](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializer-list) to set the final property
3. Do not use the passed in collection reference as a field value: **clone** the collection instead

**Solution**:

```
// ✅ THIS WORKS
class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map product;

  ProductManager({
    Map product = const {/* some initial state */},
  }) : product = Map.from(product);
}
```

The syntax of the [initializer list](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializer-list) is a bit odd to me: notice the confusing absence of `this`.

**Update:** there's another solution: make optional constructor parameter nullable.

Alternative Solution:

```
// ✅ THIS WORKS AS WELL
class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map product;

  ProductManager({
    Map? product,
  }) : product = Map.from(product ?? {/* default initial state */});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is better variant

```
class MyClass {
  Map myMap; 

  MyClass({Map myMap})
    : myMap = myMap ?? {};
}

main() {
 MyClass a = MyClass();
 a.myMap[0]=1; // Will work

 // and


 MyClass b = MyClass(myMap: {'3':5});
 b.myMap[0]=1; // Will work too
}
```